# how to make a keyboard shortcut to clear console google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an existing keyboard shortcut or a way to create a keyboard shortcut that clears the console

[image]

Comment: That's not the console, it's the network panel. There is no existing keyboard shortcut.